# Como modificar txtbox independientes y agregarlos a datos en tabla?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Tengo una Base de Datos de Access que calcula el tiempo entre dos fechas; pero  las fechas que se calculan, no se agregan a ninguna tabla.

No encuentro el porque no se agregan.

**El codigo del Formulario**

```
Private Sub Comando8_Click()
    CalculaTiempoTranscurrido CDate(Me.txtFechaI & " " & Me.txtHoraI), CDate(Me.txtFechaF & " " & Me.txtHoraF)

    MsgBox "Años: " & TiempoTranscurrido.Años & Chr(13) & "Meses: " & TiempoTranscurrido.Meses & _
            Chr(13) & "Dias: " & TiempoTranscurrido.Dias & Chr(13) & _
            "Horas: " & TiempoTranscurrido.Horas & Chr(13) & "Minutos: " & TiempoTranscurrido.Minutos & _
            Chr(13) & "Segundos: " & TiempoTranscurrido.Segundos, vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "TIEMPO TRANSCURRIDO"
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.txtFechaF = Date
    Me.txtFechaI = Date - 42
    Me.txtHoraF = #5:30:00 PM#
    Me.txtHoraI = #8:00:00 AM#
End Sub
```

**El codigo del Modulo**

```
Option Compare Database

'Tipo personalizado
Type TiempoT
    Años As Integer
    Meses As Integer
    Dias As Integer
    Horas As Integer
    Minutos As Integer
    Segundos As Integer
End Type

'TiempoTranscurrido es una variable publica definida de acuerdo al Tipo personalizado TiempoT
Public TiempoTranscurrido As TiempoT


'*******************************************************************************
'* CalculaTiempoTranscurrido
'* Calcula el tiempo transcurrido entre las dos fechas y horas pasadas como parámetros
'*******************************************************************************

Sub CalculaTiempoTranscurrido(datInicio As Date, datFin As Date)
    Dim fechaCalculo As Date

    'inicializamos los valores de la variable TiempoTranscurrido
    TiempoTranscurrido.Años = 0
    TiempoTranscurrido.Meses = 0
    TiempoTranscurrido.Dias = 0
    TiempoTranscurrido.Horas = 0
    TiempoTranscurrido.Minutos = 0
    TiempoTranscurrido.Segundos = 0

    'si la Fecha Fin es menor que la de inicio salimos sin hacer los calculos
    'En determinadas condiciones es posible que no nos importe recibir valores negativos
    'en tal caso habrá que anular estas tres líneas
    If datFin < datInicio Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'En los calculos usamos fija la fecha Fin, la de inicio la iremos
    'incrementando con la fracción ya computada.
    fechaCalculo = datInicio

    'Calculo de AÑOS
    TiempoTranscurrido.Años = DateDiff("yyyy", fechaCalculo, datFin)
    If Month(datFin) < Month(datInicio) Then
        TiempoTranscurrido.Años = TiempoTranscurrido.Años - 1
    ElseIf Month(datFin) = Month(datInicio) And Day(datFin) <= Day(datInicio) - 1 Then
        TiempoTranscurrido.Años = TiempoTranscurrido.Años - 1
    End If
    'añadimos a fechaCalculo la fracción de tiempo que acabamos de computar
    fechaCalculo = DateAdd("yyyy", TiempoTranscurrido.Años, fechaCalculo)

    'Calculo de MESES
    TiempoTranscurrido.Meses = DateDiff("m", fechaCalculo, datFin)
    If Day(datFin) < Day(datInicio) Then
        TiempoTranscurrido.Meses = TiempoTranscurrido.Meses - 1
    End If
    fechaCalculo = DateAdd("m", TiempoTranscurrido.Meses, fechaCalculo)

    'Calculo de DIAS
    TiempoTranscurrido.Dias = DateDiff("d", fechaCalculo, datFin)
    If Hour(datFin) < Hour(datInicio) Then
        TiempoTranscurrido.Dias = TiempoTranscurrido.Dias - 1
    End If
    fechaCalculo = DateAdd("d", TiempoTranscurrido.Dias, fechaCalculo)

    'Calculo de HORAS
    TiempoTranscurrido.Horas = DateDiff("h", fechaCalculo, datFin)
    If Minute(datFin) < Minute(datInicio) Then
        TiempoTranscurrido.Horas = TiempoTranscurrido.Horas - 1
    End If
    fechaCalculo = DateAdd("h", TiempoTranscurrido.Horas, fechaCalculo)

    'Calculo de MINUTOS
    TiempoTranscurrido.Minutos = DateDiff("n", fechaCalculo, datFin)
    If Second(datFin) < Second(datInicio) Then
        TiempoTranscurrido.Minutos = TiempoTranscurrido.Minutos - 1
    End If
    fechaCalculo = DateAdd("n", TiempoTranscurrido.Minutos, fechaCalculo)

    'Calculo de Segundos
    TiempoTranscurrido.Segundos = DateDiff("s", fechaCalculo, datFin)

End Sub
```

Este codigo lo adapte de http://www.mvp-access.es/marciano/ para un proyecto de nomina

*Nota: Aun lo estoy en proceso de aprendizaje de VBA. Muchas Gracias.*

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! a ese codigo le falta guardar valores en alguna tabla, por eso no actualiza ningun dato en ningun lado. No hay nada en esas lineas de codigo que haga un insert, update o algo en ninguna tabla

Answer (score -1):

Si entiendo bien, la funcion que estas implementando, le hace falta un metodo de UPDATE a la tabla de la base de datos, tus variables de FechaCalculo o FechaTranscurrido estan solo con valor, pero sin embargo, no estan en alguna funcion de agregado.